# how to make logic for pattern "*" question in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

Make the pattern

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

using loops in python

There is some problem in the logic of this for loop can u check and please tell

```
for i in range(0, 5):
     
        for j in range(0, i+1):
         
            print("* ",end=""
)
      
        print("\r")
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question please give more details concerning the problem. Just "some problem" is not sufficient.

Comment: You should describe the problem more, as "some problem" is not clear enough and it is quite hard to help you without knowing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space in the print :

```
for i in range(0, 5):
     
        for j in range(0, i+1):
         
            print("*",end="")

        print()
```

Comment: And what is the reason to print `"\r"`? A simple `print()` should be enough.

Comment: you are right :)